# Lua - Match a string with item in array?

Tags: arrays, string, lua, pattern-matching

I am new in Lua and I want to try display an item from an array, but it's like an array inside an array.

This is my list:

```
local itemlist = {
    { name="blue car", price=5000 },
    { name="red car", price=10000 },
    { name="green car", price=2000 }
}
```

And so if I would input the text "red car" I want it to output something like this:

```
The red car costs 10000 dollars.
```

How can I do this in lua?
So far I have only found some string match examples where I can see if an array contains an item, but what I want is to output that AND the price. How do I get to the price? I have no idea where to even start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need pattern matching in your simple example.

```
local str = "red car"
for _, v in ipairs(itemlist) do
    if v.name == str then
        print("The " .. v.name .. " costs " .. tostring(v.price) .. " dollars.")
    end
end
```

Comment: It works great on the first item in the list, but the second ones (red car and green car) won't get printed out. I typed in "blue car" and it displayed it perfectly. Ohhhhhhhhh nvm it works now! THANKS!!!!

Comment: By the way, how can I make the "str" check if the item is in the list. Instead of setting local str = red car", like if I type in ANY of the items names it would recognize it. And if the item is not in the list, like a Purple Car, it will say "i dont have that car in stock."

Comment: @aliazik Use a boolean flag like `local found_car = false`, if a name matches, sets it to `true` and break out of the loop. Check its value when the loop is done.

Comment: The thing is, I am doing this for a little game. And the text I type in is stored in a variable called `m.content` . So what I need to do is, if the player types "red car", it will then set the `local str = "red car"` . But I don't want to add a long if-statement like `if (m.content == 'red car') then  local str = "red car" elseif (m.content == 'blue car') then  local str = "blue car" end` . That would take so much time to make if my list contains 1000 items for example

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it now! `elseif (table.find(itemlist, m.content:lower(), 'name')) then`

Answer (score 2):

You should read about tables and tables with sequences in the manual. Then you can decide whether to use `pairs` or `ipairs` to iterate over the table.

Another approach, if the names are going to be unique, would be the change the structure:

```
local itemlist = {
    ["blue car"] = { price=5000 },
    ["red car"] = { price=10000 },
    ["green car"] = { price=2000 }
}

-- or even 

local prices = {
    ["blue car"] = 5000,
    ["red car"] = 10000,
    ["green car"] = 2000
}

print(itemlist["red car"].price);
print(prices["red car"]);
```